# Delete N nodes after M nodes in Linked list

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, traversal

I wrote a C program for deleting n nodes after m nodes. I can't figure out why its not working. Am using a head node rather than a head pointer. Is it good to use head node rather than head pointer ?

Here is my code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node* create()
{
    struct node *head=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    head->next=NULL;
    return head;
}

void insert(struct node *head,int x)
{
    struct node *temp=head;
    struct node *new=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new->data=x;
    new->next=NULL;
    while(temp->next!=NULL)
        temp=temp->next;
    temp->next=new;

}

void display(struct node *head) {
    struct node *temp=head->next;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("\n%d\n",temp->data);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}

void skipMDeleteN(struct node *head,int m,int n)
{
    int i;
    struct node *cur=head->next;
    while(cur)
    {printf("djhfj");
        for(i=1;i<m,cur!=NULL;i++)
            cur=cur->next;

        if(cur==NULL) return;

        struct node *t=cur->next;
        for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            struct node *temp=t;
            t=t->next;
            free(temp);
        }
        cur->next=t;
        cur=t;
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct node *head=create();
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
    {
        insert(head,i);
    }
    int m=2,n=2;
    skipMDeleteN(head,m,n);
    display(head);
}
```

Comment: Check this out:- http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/delete-n-nodes-after-m-nodes-of-a-linked-list/

Comment: what is the output that you are getting?Take a pen and do it on paper,believe me it will help you only.

Comment: Yeah I tried before posting the code here and it really helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixes as following:

```
for(i=1;i<m && cur != NULL;i++) //Replace ',' with &&
{
    cur=cur->next;
}
if(cur==NULL) return;

struct node *t=cur->next;
for(i=1;i<=n && t!=NULL;i++) // Check if t reaches end of node.
{
    struct node *temp=t;
    t=t->next;
    free(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified you code, and It is ok use a head pointer .

```
void skipMDeleteN(struct node *head,int m,int n)
{
    int i;
    struct node *cur=head->next; 
       // printf("djhfj");
        for(i=1;i<m&&cur!=NULL;i++)
            cur=cur->next;

        if(cur==NULL) 
            return;

        struct node *t=cur->next;
        for(i=1;i<=n&&t!= NULL;i++)
        {
            struct node *temp=t;
            t=t->next;
            free(temp);
        }
        cur->next=t;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative implementation to yours that I feel will ease the functionality you want to implement. The trick is to use a wrapper structure.

From that I would of defined my structures as follows:

```
struct llnode {
  int item;
  struct llnode *next;
};

typedef struct llnode *Node;

struct linkedlist {
  Node front;
  int length; // Optional, useful for O(1) linked list length.
};

typedef struct linkedlist *LinkedList;
```

... making the deleting k nodes after traversing n nodes much easier to implement.

The way you are implementing your list makes a lot of the implementation and client interaction very confusing and rather over complicated. Using a wrapper structure eases into a little bit of abstraction. Now, your create function would look as follows.

```
LinkedList create_LinkedList( void ) {
  // Requests a block of memory from the memory pool for a struct linked list.
  LinkedList new_LinkedList = malloc( sizeof( struct linkedlist ) );

  // Determines whether we requested a valid block of memory.
  if ( new_LinkedList == NULL ) {
    // Handle the error appropriately.
  }

  // Mutates the fields of the new linked list structure.
  new_LinkedList->front = NULL;
  new_LinkedList->length = 0;

  return new_LinkedList;
}
```

To traverse the linked list n nodes and delete k nodes -- it would be similar to how you implemented it. I will only implement the delete node function as traversing the list and deleting k number nodes is pretty straight forward if the function to delete a node is provided for you. It would be implemented as follows:

```
int delete_FrontNode( LinkedList list ) {
  // Checks pre conditions.
  assert( list != NULL ); // Ensure it is not a NULL pointer.

  // Determines whether the length is already 0.
  if ( list->length == 0 ) return -1;

  // Define a backup pointer to the front node.
  Node ptr = list->front;

  // Define the return value (the node item).
  int const ret = ptr->item;

  // Mutate the front of the linked list to point to the next node.
  list->front = list->front->next;

  // Free the original front node.
  free( ptr );

  // Decrement the length of the linked list.
  list->length -= 1;

  return ret;
}
```